# Imported GPX files into QGIS ver 2.0.1-fields missing?

Tags: qgis, gpx

Just imported GPX file into QGIS.Opened attribute table. 
where are the following fields? Latitude,Longitude,,symbol,and time . Am I missing something??I used a Garmin Oregon 300 to collect the data. Verified that all the listed fields have info in them using other [image]both Mac and Windows GPS programs.

Answer (score 4):

If you can see the points on your map, then, please, don't be worry about the first two fields!

You only need to create an expression based label for your layer, like below,

[image]

and then you'll be able to see the `latitude` & `longitude`:

[image]

Now, about the last two fields: I don't know nothing about your data, but because you are sure the `time` and the `symbol` elements exist in your `gpx` file, try to repeat the import, after deleting the `schemaLocation` reference in your `<gpx>` element. If there is a reference to a companion file, like an `xsl`, with some import rules, it must be deleted also. Below is such an example:

[image]

If, eventually, you can not see the `time` and `symbol` columns, can you upload the `gpx` file for a review?

---

**EDIT**

If you want to see the latitude and the longitude in your `attribute table` then:

- right click your layer name:

[image]

- complete as bellow and press OK:

[image]

- open up th new layer `attribute table`, `toggle editing mode` and press `field calculator` to create the latitude and longitude columns as new fields:

[image]

Now, if you are not satisfied having the latitude and longitude as `decimal degrees`, thanks to [this](http://press.underdiverwaterman.com/convert-decimal-degrees-to-dms-in-qgis/) link you can have them as `DMS`, as in OziExplorer:

[image]

Comment: Removing the schema details doesn't do anything, at least for my version of GPS Tool.

Comment: if the Andre Joost's response doesn't satisfy your requirements then can you upload the gpx file for a review? You can upload it on dropbox then you put here only the public link. There must be some rules of visibility inside,or something else tricky.

Comment: I suggest to change the field type from integer to real.

Comment: @andre-joost Thanks for the tip, I was in a hurry! I've decided to text, only to fit the both cases...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the GPS tool, you can add a GPX file from disk with `Add Vector layer`. Most GPS receivers write a GPX file into their internal memeory or memory card, which can be transferred to the PC disc; others require GPSbabel for that step.

With`Add Vector layer` you get elevation and time stamps for waypoints and track points in the attribute table.

Comment: You only get timestamps if your GPS saves them in the right fields. My 60csx puts them in the ‘cmt’ field, which sometimes contains other text. But yes, Add Vector Layer imports more fields than the GPS tool.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone who took the time to answer.I'm thrilled to receive your responses.
 I gave up on the GPS plugin and ended up using the "add Vector Layer".  I've attached an image showing what was the final result.Somehow it still didn't import the Lat/Long fields. I know they are there because programs like Cartographica (Mac) and Oziexplorer(windows) have no trouble importing them.
I'm happy to upload the file if someone would like to look at it.
My next step is using the TableManager plugin to try and sort out the fields I require.
[image]

Comment: Surely the coordinates are available, they are used to put the points at the right place. $x and $y in the field calculator will add them to the attribute table.

Comment: Wow, many,many thanks for all your help. It really was simple to do. Sorry, I'm not a programmer. This really is another language. I envy your skills.